# Add integers 20, 30, 50 and 160 using register 8-bitAL in assembly using MOVZX

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am rather confused with how to find the sum of integers using an 8-bit register AL? Any hint would be great. Thank you.

```
TITLE Add              (AddSub.asm)

; This program adds and subtracts 32-bit integers.
;Problem 1 Add 20, 30, 50,160  al  hint move ax,0 to start
; Last update: 2/1/02

TITLE Add               (AddSub.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC

    mov al,20d      
    add al,30d      
    add al,50d      
    add al,160d 
    call DumpRegs

    call writedec 
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: hint: 260 > 256. You can't do that.

Comment: I am aware, but I was told there is a way to do so using MOVZX? Thank you.

Comment: You can get 260 if you're not using AL, but AX. Worst case, AH:AL (same register viewed differently). Computing in eight bits and then zero extending that will _not_ work.

Comment: Ah I see. What does it mean by "move ax,0 to start"? So the only possible registers are AX and EAX? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a number to `AL` and there is an overflow, what you get is the low-order 8 bits of the result in `AL`, and the Carry Flag is set.  If you view the Carry Flag plus the AL register as a 9-bit quantity, it is the sum you are looking for.  (And a 9-bit quantity is large enough to represent 260.)

The instruction "ADC" stands for "Add with Carry", so if you already have `AH` set to zero, (with `MOVZX`, perhaps?) you can do `ADC AH,0` and this will essentially add the carry flag into `AH`, and then `AX` will contain your result.

There you go, that's a lot more than a hint, it is practically the solution.

Comment: I apologize, but would the code be like this:

TITLE Add               (AddSub.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC

 mov al,20d  
 add al,30d  
 add al,50d  
 adc al,160d 
 

 mov al,0FFh
 add al,1  ; CF = 1,  AL = 00
 
 call DumpRegs
 call writedec 
 exit
main ENDP
END main

Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: I am new to assembly and very noobish. Please forgive me. Thank you

Comment: Uhm, no.  `mov al, 0FFh add al, 1` makes no sense.  All you need is `adc ah, 0`, provided that `ah` was already zero before the additions.  Read my answer again.

Comment: Would it be the following:

movzx ah,0 
 mov al,20d  
 add al,30d  
 add al,50d  
 add al,160d 
 
 ADC AH, 0 

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: That would be more or less it, except that instead of `movzx ah` you need `movzx ax, 20.`  Or instead you can just do `mov ah, 0` or `xor ah,ah` all these will clear `ah`.  But why are you asking?  Can't you just try?

Comment: I mean, the suggestions that you are going to get on stackoverflow will be pointing you in the right direction, but they are not guaranteed to be 100% correct down to the minute syntax details level. For example, NASM may issue an error on `movzx ax, 20`, it might want to see it as `movzx ax, BYTE 20`. I can't tell right off the top of my head, and few people can. Nothing is guaranteed to work precisely as said, you have to try things.

Answer (score 1):

`ax` is composed from `ah` and `al`.

`movzx` is `mov` with "zero extended", can be used to copy shorter value into larger destination.

`movzx ah,0` is not legal, it's moving 8b constant into 8b register, nothing to extend (`mov ah,0` is enough then).

`movzx ax,BYTE 20` will zero extend 8 bit constant 20, and store it into 16 bit `ax` register.

This is equivalent to `mov al,20  mov ah,0` or `mov ax,WORD 20` (or few thousand other variants how to load byte value 20 into `al` and zero into `ah`, one of the common ones is to use `xor ah,ah`).

Once you have whole `ax` initialized, you can either change `add al,#i` into 16b variant `add ax,#i`, or compose that same thing from two 8b add instructions as `add al,#i` (set's CF=Carry flag, when the result did overflow 8b) `adc ah,0` (adding CF to ah).

Try to apply this to Mike's answer, if you are still lost, get some good book/tutorial/lecture.

How can you even ask something like *"So the only possible registers are AX and EAX?"*? It means you didn't read (or understand) anything about x86 assembler. Yet you are trying to write the code already? Dig into some lectures first, it takes only few weeks to re-read some good book or lecture notes several times, and everything will make then somewhat more sense. At the moment it's difficult to answer you without going trough stuff which you have in the class.